# Copy list of email attachment filenames to the clipboard

Tags: vba, outlook, clipboard, attachment

I get emails with anywhere from 1 to 30+ attachments. I need to retype their names in our order system.

I would like to get a list of the file names of all attachments, and either display it in a message box so I can copy it, or put it directly on the clipboard.

I found pieces to what I need.

What I have cycles through the list one at a time and that's not helpful.

```
Sub ListAttachments()
Dim a As Attachments
Dim myitem1 As Outlook.mailItem
Dim j As Long

Set myitem1 = ActiveExplorer().Selection.item(1)
Set a = myitem1.Attachments

For j = 1 To myitem1.Attachments.Count
    MsgBox myitem1.Attachments.item(j).DisplayName ' or .Filename
Next j

End Sub
```

This is another one I tried, but it just puts the first name on the clipboard:

```
Sub CopyToClipboardTest()
Dim M As Outlook.mailItem
Dim Buf As MSForms.DataObject

    Set M = ActiveExplorer().Selection.item(1)
    Set Buf = New MSForms.DataObject
    Buf.SetText M.Attachments.item(1).FileName
    Buf.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

Comment: As a quick fix, why not replace `MsgBox` by `Debug.Print` in your first piece of code.  This will output the list to the Immediate Window from which you can copy and paste.

Comment: This is for more than one person in my office, I don't want them to have to open VBA to get the list. right now our work around is saving the email as a text file (file save as) and then opening that to get the attachment list.

Answer (score 0):

The debug.print gave me an idea! I ended up with the following that copies it to the clipboard AND puts it in a message box. Thanks Tony.

```
Sub ListAttachments()

'declare somethings
Dim a As Attachments
Dim myitem1 As Outlook.mailItem
Dim j As Long
Dim myText As String
Set myitem1 = ActiveExplorer().Selection.item(1)
Set a = myitem1.Attachments

'this isn't needed but it makes it look nicer
myText = "Files:" & vbLf

'cycles through each attachment, including images in the email, 
'and adds them to the 'myText' with a line break after each
For j = 1 To myitem1.Attachments.Count
    myText = myText & vbLf & myitem1.Attachments.item(j).DisplayName ' or .Filename
Next j

'These four lines are only needed for copying to the clipboard, but they require FM20.dll be 'on'
'they can be removed if you don't want to enable fm20.dll or if the message box is fine.
'remember, in windows, you can press ctrl+c to copy the text in a message box
Dim Buf As MSForms.DataObject
Set Buf = New MSForms.DataObject
Buf.SetText myText
Buf.PutInClipboard

'displays the final message box that I can copy and use elsewhere.
MsgBox myText

End Sub
```